# How do you append a string built with interpolation of vars and STDIN to a file?

Tags: linux, bash

Can someone fix this for me.
It should copy a version log file to backup after moving to a repo directory
Then it automatically appends line given as input to the log file with some formatting.
That's it.

Assume existence of log file and test directory.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Git/test
cp versionlog.MD .versionlog.MD.old
LOGDATE="$(date --utc +%m-%d-%Y)"
read -p "MSG > " VHMSG |
VHENTRY="- **${LOGDATE}** | ${VHMSG}"
cat ${VHENTRY} >> versionlog.MD
```

shell output

```sh
virufac@box:~/Git/test$ ~/.logvh.sh 
MSG > testing script


EOF
EOL]

EOL
e
E
```

CTRL + C to get out of stuck in reading lines of input

```sh
virufac@box:~/Git/test$ cat versionlog.MD
```

directly outputs the markdown

```
# Version Log
## version 0.0.1 established 01-22-2020
*Working Towards Working Mission 1 Demo in 0.1 *
- **01-22-2020** | discovered faker.Faker and deprecated old namelessgen



EOF
EOL]

EOL
e
E
```

I finally got it to save the damned input lines to the file instead of just echoing the command I wanted to enter on the screen and not executing it. But... why isn't it adding the lines built from the VHENTRY variable... and why doesn't it stop reading after one line sometimes and this time not. You could see I was trying to do something to tell it to stop reading the input.

After some realizing a thing I had done in the script was by accident... I tried to fix it and saw that the `|` at the end of the read command was seemingly the only reason the script did any of what it did save to the file in the first place.

I would have done this in python3 if I had know this script wouldn't be the simplest thing I had ever done. Now I just have to know how you do it after all the time spent on it so that I can remember never to think a shell script will save time again.

Comment: Don't put `~` inside quotes, that prevents it from expanding into the home directory.

Comment: `why isn't it adding the lines built from the VHENTRY variable` - `read` stops reading after one line. But because `VHENTRY="..."` part was executed in a subshell, it caused `VHENTRY` to be empty. So `cat ${VHENTRY}` became just `cat` and `cat` was reading what you typed. If you would `cat "${VHENTRY}"` then `cat` would print an error message. Use `set -x` to debug shell scripts.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. I don't know why I put that there. I realzied that, removed it, tested it again, and thought I pasted the correct output. So the problem still persists.

Comment: @KamilCuk Wow, you helped me understand that I have a lot to learn before I try writing scripts like these in bash. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `printf` to write a string to a file. `cat` tries to read from a file named in the argument list. And when the argument is `-` it means to read from standard input until EOF. So your script is hanging because it's waiting for you to type all the input.

Don't put quotes around the path when it starts with `~`, as the quotes make it a literal instead of expanding to the home directory.

Get rid of `|` at the end of the `read` line. `read` doesn't write anything to stdout, so there's nothing to pipe to the following command.

There isn't really any need for the `VHENTRY` variable, you can do that formatting in the `printf` argument.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Git/test
cp versionlog.MD .versionlog.MD.old
LOGDATE="$(date --utc +%m-%d-%Y)"
read -p "MSG > " VHMSG
printf -- '- **%s** | %s\n' "${LOGDATE}" "$VHMSG" >> versionlog.MD
```

Comment: I got 

```
$ ~/.logvh.sh 
MSG > testi
/home/virufac/.logvh.sh: line 7: printf: - : invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

Comment: Added a `--` option to `printf` so it won't treat the format string as an option.

Comment: I am amazed that this was as many things as it took into account and in some ways much simpler than what I was trying still.